# In a single form, linking two instances of two models with habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am using Rails 3.

I have a Product model and a Group model (a group has_many users, through membership).

I would like to build the `new.html.erb` form for the product model, and at the end of the form, I would like the user to be able to choose members from which group(s) can have access to the product he wants to add.

So, my goal is to list the groups to which the user belongs to, adding a checkbox for each of them. Then, create the associations between the product inserted and the different groups the user selected when the form is submitted, but I really do not understand how to achieve this, as all the documentation I have read use the BUILD or CREATE method that defines a new instance of group, instead of an existing one.

Is it possible with a nested form, and a HABTM relationship between product and group ? Or should I use a nested form with a has_many_through association using new model product_group_relationship ? Or should I use something else than a nested form ?

I'm quite new in Rails and a little bit lost here, so if some experienced guy could guide me a little bit, it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form_for helper comes with a nice package of extra methods like: fields_for wich makes you able to add nested attributes for has_many_through relations.

I suggest reading these:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

And make sure you set your model validations accordingly

Comment: OK, so I need to change to a has_many_through relationship to do what I would like to do I understand well your answer?

Comment: well from your quote: "I have a Product model and a Group model (a group has_many users, through membership)" that seems like the right solution although fields_for is for both has_many and has_many through so see for yourself :)

Comment: the "has_many_through" here is between GROUP and USER models, and the associations I am trying to do are between GROUP and PRODUCT models, that are currently in HABTM relationship. Do you keep your answer then or would you change it ? :-)

Comment: I will stick to my answer sir. make sure however you read the docs carefully about the model validations and nested attributes